# Spring Security - 401 Unauthorized access

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

I've created a form that sends the data to my backend, which persists it into the database [image]

This works well as long as I have .permitAll() on my antMatcher, but when I try to secure it so that only admins can make that call (admin role in the DB is ROLE_ADMIN), it returns a 401 Unauthorized Access with no message. I've tried

- .hasRole("ADMIN")
- .hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")
- .hasAuthority("ADMIN")
- .hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")

None of them works.
[image]

[image]

My request looks like this (posting for the headers):

[image]

My SecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    securedEnabled = true,
    jsr250Enabled = true,
    prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
    return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/**/*.png",
                    "/**/*.gif",
                    "/**/*.svg",
                    "/**/*.jpg",
                    "/**/*.html",
                    "/**/*.css",
                    "/**/*.js")
                    .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                    .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/book/**")
                    .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/author/**")
//                        .permitAll()
                    .hasAnyRole("ROLE_ADMIN", "ADMIN", "ROLE_USER", "USER", "ROLE_ROLE_ADMIN", 
"ROLE_ROLE_USER")
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();

    http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
}
```

My UserDetailsServiceImpl class:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

    return UserDetailsImpl.create(user);
}

@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserById(Integer id) {
    User user = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(
            () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with id: " + id)
    );

    return UserDetailsImpl.create(user);
}
}
```

My JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint class:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint.class);

@Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, 
AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
    logger.error("Unauthorized access. Message:", e.getMessage());
    httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, e.getMessage());
}
}
```

My JwtAuthenticationFilter:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Autowired
private JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

@Autowired
private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationFilter.class);


@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse 
httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(httpServletRequest);

        if(StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
            Integer userId = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwt);

            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserById(userId);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new 
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());

            authentication.setDetails(new 
WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", e);
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
}

private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

The JWT Token's validity is properly checked. That's not the issue at hand.
Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
Added implementation of UserDetailsImpl:

```
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {
private Integer id;

@JsonIgnore
private String email;

private String name;

@JsonIgnore
private String password;

private boolean isAdmin;

private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

public UserDetailsImpl(Integer id, String email, String name, String 
password, boolean isAdmin, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> 
authorities) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.authorities = authorities;
    this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
}

public static UserDetailsImpl create(User user) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream().map(role ->
            new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().name())
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());

    boolean isAdmin = false;

    for(Role role:  user.getRoles()) {
        if(RoleName.ROLE_ADMIN.equals(role.getName())) {
            isAdmin = true;
        }
    }

    return new UserDetailsImpl(
            user.getId(),
            user.getEmail(),
            user.getName(),
            user.getPassword(),
            isAdmin,
            authorities
    );
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return email;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public boolean isAdmin() {
    return isAdmin;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return authorities;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    UserDetailsImpl that = (UserDetailsImpl) o;
    return Objects.equals(id, that.id);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {

    return Objects.hash(id);
}
```

Added this to check if the authorities are present after UserDetailsImpl.create(user) call:
[image]

Output:

[image]

Login part of the AuthenticationController:

[image]

Comment: Does your user have Admin ROLE?

Comment: Could you please share your Implementation of  UserDetailsImpl.create() ? Maybe you're not granting the proper role and authorities at that moment

Comment: can you show us what the output of `userDetails.getAuthorities()` is?

Comment: @tashkhisi As far as I can tell, yes, it should have it.

Comment: @Youri I added at the end of the post the implementation and the output of .getauthorities after .create(user)

Comment: @Aman I added the output of .getAuthorities after the .create(user) function gets called.

Comment: Thanks, it looks fine to me... Quick question: Why do you call your method "create" even though you're fetching an already existing user ? And your 401 error is happening after you've succesfully logged in ?
 Have you tried to switch to authentificated(), just to check if it works ? 
As it is, your config looks fine to me and the role attribution too though...

Comment: I didn't see any problem on the codes, may be you should check the `accessToken`.

Comment: @Youri .anyRequest().authenticated() should allow access to any resource that's not mentioned specifically, right? I have that at the end of the "chain", after the antMatchers, so commenting the /api/author/** antMatcher should do the trick.  I've tried that just now, it still returns the same 401 Unauthorized access with no message.

Comment: @Aman The accessToken is valid. Every 10 minutes it expires, and the TokenProvider lets me know if I try to make a call and it's expired (I haven't implemented to refreshToken yet, so I have to relog. In the JwtAuthenticationFilter class in the doFilterInternal method, the tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt) returns true, which means the accessToken provided is both not-expired and correct. (It returns false if the token is expired, for example, I've tested that too)

Comment: @Kanami oooh, my bad, I did not see that... Actually  ".anyRequest().authenticated();"
 specifies that you need to be authenticated to access the ressources/page, so its the contrary of what you just said, you can look into this https://www.baeldung.com/java-config-spring-security (section 4).
So it seems like you got an authentication + roles at the same time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are not updating the `SecurityContextHolder`. Unable to put it in a comment, so I wrote it here.

```
authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest))
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication); //this seems missing
```

Comment: Oh, it is missing in the JwtAuthenticationFilter class. I'll see if that does the trick.